# File.ReadAllText is vulnerable to SQL Injection

Tags: c#, sql-injection

I am trying to resolve the SQL injection dependencies from my C# web application project. I am executing SQL queries on the database by reading them from an internal SQL file(part of the project). I am using `File.ReadAllText` function to read the SQL query from a file.

Is `File.ReadAllText` vulnerable to SQL injection? If yes, how to avoid a SQL injection vulnerability in this case?

```
File.ReadAllText(sqlScriptFilePath)
```

Comment: How would a function that doesn't run SQL be vulnerable to a SQL Injection? What you do with the result (the query read) is a completely different question

Comment: How did the SQL get into the file? Is it static SQL? Typed in by a customer? Something else?

Comment: If those SQLs in files are trusted then no.

Comment: SQL injection boils down to *mixing code and data via string manipulation*, such that it's possible for the code/data distinction to become lost. Since the file API, *itself*, doesn't do those things, it's not vulnerable itself, but how you're *using* the strings you read from it (and where those strings came from) may build towards an injection vulnerability.

Comment: Yes, It's static SQL. All SQL files are part of a project and trusted.

Comment: Well then you are fine.

Comment: Rather than reading SQL from files, consider using stored procedures, views and table-valued functions or (if you *must* have hard-coded queries) consider embedding these as string resources into an assembly (`resx` and friends). The latter isn't necessarily easier to use than flat files, but it is generally easier to secure, as web servers are far more reluctant to serve up binaries out of the box, even if you accidentally get the file permissions wrong. Your DBA will be a lot happier if you use stored procedures, though.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yup I agree :) Another helpful one is to use SQL Parameters

Comment: @JeroenMostert the choice of how to deploy SQL is much more complex than that; my DB admins would *shoot me* (and I don't mean figuratively) if I proposed that. It depends hugely on context. It is *actively wrong* to suggest that all access should be done via SPs (or views or whatever). There are scenarios where that is absolutely true, There are scenarios where it is actively wrong. And there are scenarios where it won't matter much either way,

Comment: @MarcGravell: ...then I amend my comment to "your DBA *might* be a lot happier". If you read my comment as "stored procedures should be used universally", well, that's definitely not how I meant it. I will stand by my recommendation to *consider* it 100%, though. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so assuming you have `SelectAll.txt`. Inside `SelectAll.txt`, contains a single line: `SELECT * FROM Users;`, and your C# program basically loads this .txt file and executes this select statement, then NO... It's definitely not vulnerable to an SQL injection..

File.ReadAllText, basically reads whatever is in a file to a variable or so. This variable is stored in your system's memory (RAM). Unless your attacker has a way to access your memory and edit the values of the variables, you're pretty much safe :).

And lastly here's a guide that you would find very helpful as I did too myself :) [What is SQL Injection (SQLi) and How to Fix It](https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/)

Comment: But sqlScriptFilePath suggests the script filename and path is passed as argument. If I pass it an url, and ReadAllText handles urls correcly (which it probably doesn't do), then I could upload a SQL script somewhere, e.g. pastebin, and have that executed...